# How to create an image file from drawable path

Tags: android, image, bitmap

hi everyone i'm an android developer and i'm trying to create an image file from a drawable resource, like this :

```
 Bitmap btm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.image1);
 Bitmap btm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathname);
 btm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
 File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator + "temporary_file.jpg");
    try {
        f.createNewFile();
        new FileOutputStream(f).write(bytes.toByteArray());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But what i need is create the file starting from the path of image1, 
I tried to use :

```
String pathname = currentLevel.getImagePath();
Bitmap btm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathname);
btm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
```

But it does not work:

```
E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: android.resource:/com.example.utente.guessimageferes/drawable/immagine1 (No such file or directory)
```

also with

```
String pathname ="android.resource://com.example.utente.guessimageferes/drawable/immagine1"
```

i have the same problem it's possible make that i want?

Comment: What is currentLevel object?

Comment: for each level of my game  i set  a different image  so currentLevel.getImagePath(); returns the path of the drawable image at the current level. but also with the manual entry of the path i have the same error

Comment: What is wrong with the code in the first block? Except for the second line which you should remove.

Answer (score 0):

> what i need is  starting from the path of image1

There is no path to `image1`. `image1` is a resource. It is a file *on your development machine*. It is not a file on the device. Hence, it does not have a path.

Comment: So i can't take this : android.resource://com.example.utente.guessimageferes/drawable/image1, and  create a file on the storage of the device ?

Comment: @Rachid: Correct. That is a `String` representation of a `Uri`. It is no more a valid file path than `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40349786/how-to-create-an-image-file-from-drawable-path/40349970` is a valid file path.

Comment: Ok thankyou!  So now i have understood that I Need to set dinamicly the drawable resource id  is that possibile?

Comment: @Rachid: No. You cannot create resources at runtime. You cannot assign resource IDs at runtime.